# C# Directory jumps back to sourcePath

Tags: c#

i found a Code in the internet that checks the directorys between two paths and creates them if they do not exists in the destination Path.
But there is one thing which i don't understand, why does it hopp back to the source path?

Example:

SourcePath = C:\ABC
DestinatonPath = C:\Program Files (x86)\Alex GmbH

in the folder "ABC" are two folders with the name "a" and "b" and "a" has 2 Subfolders called "b" and "c". the other one is empty.

i also debuggt it, but it just hopped back from
C:\ABC\a\b to C:\ABC and i just freaking don't understand why.

Code:

```
     public void directories(string source, string dest, bool copySubDirs = true)
     {
          var dir = new DirectoryInfo(source);
          DirectoryInfo[] dirs = dir.GetDirectories();

          if (!Directory.Exists(dest))
          {
              Directory.CreateDirectory(dest);
          }

          foreach (DirectoryInfo subdir in dirs)
          {

             string tempPath = Path.Combine(dest, subdir.Name);
             directories(subdir.FullName, tempPath, copySubDirs);
           } 
        }
```

If you do understand why it jumps back to the source, can you please explain it with easy words (thanks a lot mate).

(and for those who think i did not think about it or used a bit time to check the code, believe me. i did and now im here :) )

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "jumps back".  This creates directories, but this never changes the current directory.

Comment: i mean the value in "dest", after it is a the point "C:\ABC\a\b" and there are no other subdirectories, it "jumps back" to C:\ABC and switches to C\ABC\b and checks there the other subdirectories and creates them, which is irritating cause i dont understand why it goes back to C:\ABC, i never gave the command to do this

Comment: i mean i could be a feature of DirectoryInfo, that if there are no other subdirectories left it just goes back to C:\ABC but i didnt found a line about it in the microsoft documentation of DirectoryInfo

Comment: You do see that it's recursive, right?  It creates the `dest` folder, then for every subdir in source (`a` and `b`), it calls itself again.  This time, source will be `C:\ABC\a`, then it calls again with `C:\ABC\b`, but when those return, the original source is still `C:\ABC`.  It has nothing to do with `DirectoryInfo`.  Insert some debug prints -- that might help you follow the flow.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just confused by the recursive calls.  Let's say we have

```
C:\ABC\a
C:\ABC\a\b
C:\ABC\a\c
C:\ABC\b
```

OK, so we call

```
directories( "C:/ABC", "C:/Alex" );
```

That's going to enumerate all the subdirectories of C:/ABC.  Inside the
foreach call, it will do these calls in order:

```
1.  directories( "C:/ABC/a", "C:/Alex/a" )
2.  directories( "C:/ABC/b", "C:/Alex/b" )
```

So, we call `directories` AGAIN.  The first call will enumerate the subdirectories of C:/ABC/a, and finds two.  So ITS loop is going to call:

```
1.1. directories( "C:/ABC/a/b", "C:/Alex/a/b" )
1.2. directories( "C:/ABC/a/c", "C:/Alex/a/c" )
```

We're now nested three functions deep: `directories` called `directories` which called `directories`.  Each of those calls will create one subdirectory, after which it returns to the outer function, which does call #2.  That call finds
there's nothing in C:/ABC/b, so it returns.

In the outer function, none of the parameters have changed.  `source` is still "C:\ABC" and `dest` is still "C:\Alex".

So, we had the following calls, in this order:

```
directories( "C:/ABC", "C:/Alex" )
    directories( "C:/ABC/a", "C:/Alex/a" )
       directories( "C:/ABC/a/b", "C:/Alex/a/b" )
       directories( "C:/ABC/a/c", "C:/Alex/a/c" )
    directories( "C:/ABC/b", "C:/Alex/b" )
```